# Box shadow doesn't work on Bootstrap input field

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to apply some CSS to a bootstrap input field, but somehow I couldn't see the `box-shadow`. When I inspect the element in Chrome, it seems that CSS `box-shadow` is applied to that field and CSS of `form-control` was over written. Is there something wrong with how I defined the input field? Could someone please help? Many thanks!

```css
#amount {
  min-width: 56px;
  width: 224px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border: solid 1px #e2e2e2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="text-center input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon2">Payment amount</span>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="amount" value="1.00">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inset box-shadow seems to be working on your example, it's just very faint because of the 0.12 in your colour declaration. Does it help if you increase the opacity, for example set it to 0.5 instead of 0.12?

**Initial response:**

*The ID in your CSS (#payment_amount) doesn't match the ID in your HTML (#amount) so it won't be applied.
Would it be better to apply the style to .form-control, or are you only wanting to apply it to this one specific field?*

Comment: Thanks! I'm very sorry that was a typo. I've changed it now. It still doesn't work. Yes I only want to apply it to this one field.

Comment: The inset box-shadow seems to be working on your example, it's just very faint because of the 0.12 in your colour declaration. Does it help if you set this to 0.5?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Yes that was the problem. If you move that to an answer I'd accept that

Comment: I've updated my original answer to include the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
box-shadow: -1px 3px 12px rgba(187, 195, 197, 0.6);
```

you can use this.

Comment: Thanks man but that shadow seems to go outwards instead of inside that input field. How do you translate the values I provided to the values in your answer?

Comment: for shadow inside you can do like this  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;

Comment: okay. try to add !important in your box shadow maybe have a other box- shadow priorities so you can add "!important". kindly visit the link 

http://codepen.io/myco27/pen/qRwWMB

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add more hierarchy to the rule, and then it won't be over written by the Bootstrap styles...

Write it like this...

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) !Important;
```

That should be enough.